# Ascending order 5 numbers using If else in C#

Tags: c#

I wanna know where is the problem and can I fix this.

```
        int a = 15, b = 5, c = 1, d = 30, e = 25;
        int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, num4 = 0, num5 = 0;

        // checking value of A against the other fourth values
        if (a < b && a < c && a < d && a < e)
            num1 = a;

        if (a > b && a < c && a < d && a < e)
            num1 = b;

        if (a > b && a > c && a < d && a < e)
            num1 = c;

        if (a > b && a > c && a > d && a < e)
            num1 = d;

        if (a > b && a > c && a > d && a > e)
            num1 = e;

        // checking value of B against the other fourth values
        if (b < a && b < c && b < d && b < e)
            num2 = a;

        if (b > a && b < c && b < d && b < e)
            num2 = b;

        if (b > a && b > c && b < d && b < e)
            num2 = c;

        if (b > a && b > c && b > d && b < e)
            num2 = d;

        if (b > a && b > c && b > d && b > e)
            num2 = e;

        // checking value of C against the other fourth values
        if (c < a && c < b && c < d && c < e)
            num3 = a;

        if (c > a && c < b && c < d && c < e)
            num3 = b;

        if (c > a && c > b && c < d && c < e)
            num3 = c;

        if (c > a && c > b && c > d && c < e)
            num3 = d;

        if (c > a && c > b && c > d && c > e)
            num3 = e;

        // checking value of D against the other fourth values
        if (d < a && d < b && d < c && d < e)
            num4 = a;

        if (d > a && d < b && d < c && d < e)
            num4 = b;

        if (d > a && d > b && d < c && d < e)
            num4 = c;

        if (d > a && d > b && d > c && d < e)
            num4 = d;

        if (d > a && d > b && d > c && d > e)
            num4 = e;

        // checking value of E against the other fourth values
        if (e < a && e < b && e < c && e < d)
            num5 = a;

        if (e > a && e < b && e < c && e < d)
            num5 = b;

        if (e > a && e > b && e < c && e < d)
            num5 = c;

        if (e > a && e > b && e > c && e < d)
            num5 = d;

        if (e > a && e > b && e > c && e > d)
            num5 = e;

        Console.WriteLine("Ranks from Lowest to Highest" + num1 + " " + num2 + " " + num3 + " " + num4 + " " + num5);


        Console.ReadKey();
```

The Output should be `Ranks from Lowest to Highest 1, 5, 15, 25, 30` but when I ran my console the output is `Ranks from Lowest to Highest 0, 15, 25, 30`.

Comment: The preferred way is to create an array, put all the values in and sort.

Comment: As @Tushar said, example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bca05287-d585-4650-84fc-abc86cb2b276/sort-integers-from-lowest-to-highest?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 0):

> > I wanna know where is the problem ...

First of all, the overall logic is not sound.

The first and second `if` statements are okay and would correctly identify either `a` or `b` as the least of the values.  But now consider the third statement.

```
if (a > b && a > c && a < d && a < e)
    num1 = c;
```

If that returns true, it only reveals the relative position of `a`, not the position of `c`!  If we manually sorted the variables, they could be in **any of the following orders** and the if statement would return true for all of them.

```
 b c a d e
 c b a d e
 b c a e d
 c b a e d
```

So that line of code could be rewritten as

```
if (a > b && a > c && a < d && a < e)
    num3 = a;
```

Likewise, the entire first set of five if statements are all about what position `a` takes, not what the first element is!  Even your code comment indicates that it is about 'A', so the assignments are all wrong.

So you might be tempted to try the following instead:

```
if (a < b && a < c && a < d && a < e)
    num1 = a;
if (a > b && a < c && a < d && a < e)
    num2 = a;
if (a > b && a > c && a < d && a < e)
    num3 = a;
if (a > b && a > c && a > d && a < e)
    num4 = a;
if (a > b && a > c && a > d && a > e)
    num5 = a;
```

And if you did, the values would be technically correct...
**BUT they would not not cover all possible combinations!**  Here are only a few statements that you would be missing...

```
if (a > b && a > c && a > e && a < d)
    num4 = a;
if (a > b && a > d && a > e && a < c)
    num4 = a;
if (a > c && a > d && a > e && a < b)
    num4 = a;
```

and those are just for the variable `a`!  You would have to increase your code by at least 35 more `if` statements to capture all possibilities.  Mathematically the total number of such conditions increases like `n!` (factorial... 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 *...), so adding just one more number to your list of variables would have been even more ridiculous.  Oh, and what would happen if any of the numbers were equal?  The whole thing would fail again and you'd have to change some operators to <= and >=.

> > ... and can I fix this...

If this is for a programming class, you likely need to go back and review what you have learned to properly handle this.

Similar to other comments, you need to learn how to program using arrays, loops and other formal programming ideas.  Not only will that make these tasks easier, but you will likely enjoy programming more.  But learning to sort arrays is also not trivial and is a significant topic for beginners.  There are numerous sorting algorithms and a proper programming education will usually comb through at least 4 or 5 basic array-sorting algorithms (bubble sort, insertion sort, quick sort, etc.), and that doesn't even cover linked lists and binary trees.

The easier way out is to learn how to use pre-programmed objects like lists and dictionaries that already have sorting capabilities.  But even that should be preceded with a proper introduction to objects and programming libraries.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. This is just me learning c# in our class I'm still a beginner. This is just a challenge by our professor using only If statements output the given numbers in the ascending numbers. Thought I could have your opinion on the method I used. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you wrote it in very unpractical manner. Basically you have collection of numbers you want to sort.

Writing thousands of `if`s is not very readable and mainanable.

One issue here:

```
Console.WriteLine("Ranks from Lowest to Highest" + num1 + " " + num2 + " " + num3 + " " + num4 + " " + num5);
```

doesn't match your output:

```
Ranks from Lowest to Highest 0, 15, 25, 30
```

because you are printing 5 numbers and your output shows just four... So it cannot be your actual output.

There is very clean way of soring numbers using collections, such as `Array` with help of LINQ extension methods:

```
int[] array = new int[] {a, b, c, d, e };
Console.WriteLine("Ranks from Lowest to Highest:");
array.OrderBy(i => i).ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```